# c#, type not found?

Tags: c#

Trying to unit test some simple code for a class project, however in my test code - it keeps telling me that my InventorySelect could not be found.  It asks me if I am missing a using statement ect, but that is all correct as far as I can see.

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Home
{
    class InventoryType
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Selects the inventory type and returns the selected value
        /// </summary>
        public class InventorySelect
        {
            private string inventoryTypes;
            public String InventoryTypes
            {
                set
                {
                    inventoryTypes = value;
                }

                get
                {
                    return inventoryTypes;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Validate that the inventory is returning some sort of value
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public bool Validate()
            {
                if (InventoryTypes == null) return false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Test Code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Home.InventoryType.InventorySelect;

namespace HomeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestInventoryTypeCase
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestInventoryTypeClass()
        {
            InventorySelect select = new InventorySelect();
            select.inventoryTypes = "Collection";

            if (Validate() = true)
                Console.WriteLine("Test Passed");
            else
                if (Validate() = false)
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Returned False");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Failed To Run");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You accidentally nested your classes. The inner class is called `InventoryType.InventorySelect`.

Comment: As CodesInChaos said, you have nested your classes. Also the default visibility of any C# class is internal and hence InventoryType will not be visible to the test project.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Post your comment as an answer

Comment: Your test methods should use `Assert` calls. E.g. `Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult)` or `Assert.IsTrue(foo)`.

Comment: To access internal classes from another assembly, you can use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). This is useful for testing. But in your case, unnesting the classes is probably a better choice.

Comment: And `=` is the assignment operator in C#, not the equality operator. For equality checking, use `==`.

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to do `if (Validate() == true)` you can just do `if (Validate())` and you also accidentally used `=` instead of `==` in your `if` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes are nested, and your outer class is internal (not declared `public`).  Either move your inner class out of the outer class, or 1) make the outer class public, and 2) qualify your reference to `InventorySelect` with the outer class name, i.e. `InventoryType.InventorySelect`.

Comment: the outer class is internal not private.

Answer (score 3):

In your test project, you must add a reference to the (assembly of the) project to be tested.

---

EDIT: Your nested class `InventorySelect` is inside a class that is not declared as public. Declare class `InventoryType` as public. You will have to create an instance with

```
var select = new InventoryType.InventorySelect();
```

Comment: there is a reference to the home project

Answer (score 2):

Your `InventoryType` class is not `public`! mark it as `public` and recompile it. C# classes are `internal` by default.